# Apache Camel java.lang.ClassCastException when building route dynamically from Spring XML configuration components

Tags: apache-camel, classcastexception

We build camel routes dynamically based on configuration parameters stored in the database. We have generic class that builds all camel routes. Some of the parameters just presented as raw Camel Spring XML. Class that builds camel routes extends RouteBuilder and here is portion of the code constructing Camel route:

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        RouteDefinition route = from(inputFile);
        configureSpringXMLActivity(0, route, convertBodyXml);
        configureSpringXMLActivity(5, route, setHeaderXml);
    }

    void configureSpringXMLActivity(final Integer seq, final RouteDefinition route, final String xmlConfig)
            throws Exception {
        ActivityIdentifier identifier = new CamelActivityIdentifier(seq);
        route.process(new ActivityHandoverProcessor(identifier));
        final ChoiceDefinition choice = route.choice().when(new ActivityPredicate(identifier));

        RouteContext routeContext = new DefaultRouteContext(camelContext, route, route.getInputs().get(0),
                camelContext.getRoutes());

        final StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlConfig);
        Object result = esb.getConfigUnmarshaller().unmarshal(reader);
        if (result != null) {
            ProcessorDefinition<?> processorDefinition = (ProcessorDefinition<?>) result;
            Processor processor = processorDefinition.createProcessor(routeContext);
            choice.process(processor);
        }
```

where

```
/** setHeader xml. */
    private final String setHeaderXml = "<setHeader headerName=\"extractFileName\" xmlns=\"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring\"><simple>${body}</simple></setHeader>";

    /** convertBody xml. */
    private final String convertBodyXml = "<convertBodyTo xmlns=\"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring\" type=\"java.lang.String\"/>";
```

When we start camel context it produces exception on creating setHeader processor.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.model.ProcessDefinition cannot be cast to org.apache.camel.model.SetHeaderDefinition
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementObjectStrategy.getManagedObjectForProcessor(DefaultManagementObjectStrategy.java:355)
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy.getManagedObjectForProcessor(DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy.java:515)
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy.getManagedObjectForService(DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy.java:467)
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy.onServiceAdd(DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy.java:378)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:338)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:182)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3496)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3426)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3203)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3059)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2854)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2873)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2819)
```

In Camel (version 2.17.0) source code - class DefaultManagementObjectStrategy:

```
..........
   } else if(target1 instanceof SetHeaderProcessor) {
                    answer = new ManagedSetHeader(context, (SetHeaderProcessor)target1, (SetHeaderDefinition)definition);
.........
```

it fails when casting (SetHeaderDefinition)definition

However, there is no issue with my first activity - convertBodyXml. In the same Camel class:

```
if(target1 instanceof ConvertBodyProcessor) {
                    answer = new ManagedConvertBody(context, (ConvertBodyProcessor)target1, definition);
```

In this case Camel code did not need to cast definition to create managed object: ..., definition)

DefaultManagementObjectStrategy class does casting to specific definition when creating some managed object but not on the others.

Could you please recommend how to get around ClassCastException, but still build route from generic ProcessorDefinition objects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like an awfully complicated approach for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructing `Processor` from `ProcessorDefinition` and calling process method on `ChoiceDefinition`, it is possible to just call `addOutput` method with `ProcessorDefinition` parameter on `ChoiceDefinition` directly.

Basically, `choice.addOutput(processorDefinition);`

Here is updated snippet:

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        RouteDefinition route = from(inputFile);
        configureSpringXMLActivity(0, route, convertBodyXml);
        configureSpringXMLActivity(5, route, setHeaderXml);
    }

    void configureSpringXMLActivity(final Integer seq, final RouteDefinition route, final String xmlConfig)
            throws Exception {
        ActivityIdentifier identifier = new CamelActivityIdentifier(seq);
        route.process(new ActivityHandoverProcessor(identifier));
        final ChoiceDefinition choice = route.choice().when(new ActivityPredicate(identifier));


        final StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlConfig);
        Object result = esb.getConfigUnmarshaller().unmarshal(reader);
        if (result != null) {
            ProcessorDefinition<?> processorDefinition = (ProcessorDefinition<?>) result;
            choice.addOutput(result);
        }
```

I hope it will help someone